# JavaFX adding FXML to and plain java controllers

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

My first post, be gentle please.

I am making a JavaFX GUI for a simple game.
I have an FXML layout loaded via FXML file loader here:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

Then I create a button in Main.java:

```
Button button = new Button("Jp", view);
```

And in order to display:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
primaryStage.show();
```

Question: How on earth I can combine FXML layout and plain java Button object to be on the same scene ? Is it like apples and oranges, impossible to combine ?
My IDE is not letting me invoke the method recomended from java docs:

```
root.getChildren().add();
```

and so on...

Please help me and/or  point me in some direction, I really tried...

Answer (score 0):

The [`getChildren()` method defined in `Parent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--) is a `protected` method: therefore you cannot access it from your `Main` class, which is why your code won't compile.

[`Pane` overrides this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--) and makes it `public`, so assuming the root element of your FXML file is a `Pane` (or subclass of `Pane`), you just need to be more specific about the type of root. In other words, again assuming your FXML is as I expect, change

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

to

```
Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

Comment: Thank's a million James_D ! I will go for some HBox and other containers, and see what sticks. Just needed that to test some solution.